# (Re)-defining (==) for class Eq

Tags: haskell

In the following example:

```
data ColourName 
  = White
  | Grey
  | Gray
  | Black
  | Blue
  -- ...
  -- hundreds more of colours
  -- ...
  | LastColor
  deriving (Read, Show, Eq)
```

I'd like to redefine `(==)` so that `Grey` and `Gray` evaluate as *equal*.

Obviously, one way would be to *not* include `Eq` in `deriving`, however, then I'd have to define

```
(==) :: ColourName
(==) White White = True
(==) Gray Gray = True
(==) Grey Grey = True
(==) Gray Grey = True
(==) Grey Gray = True
(==) Black Black = True
-- frickin' log of other colors, hundreds of lines of typing
(==) LastColor LastColor = True
(==) a b = False
```

which is nothing I plan to do.

I also can't do

```
instance Eq ColourName where
    (==) :: ColourName -> ColourName -> Bool
    (==) Gray Grey = True
    (==) Grey Gray = True
    (==) a b = (a == b)
```

because this leads to an infinite recursion, is basically underdefined.

Is there a way out?

(No, I don't want to use `data Colour = Colour String` or similar. I want the valid colours to be represented as an enumeration, such providing automatic validation, but want to allow spelling variation for the end users of the module!)

Comment: X-Y Problem all the way. You don't want to do this. What do you want?

Comment: @Ramon Snir: It's right there in the question: I want to define a function `(==)` which equates two data constructors, but if possible I'd like to find a digestable, short notation for it, not enumerating every possible equality (which is error prone). What do you mean by "what do you want"?

Comment: Two different constructors are by definition *different*. Why would you want to have both `Gray` and `Grey` as constructors? Choose one which will be the real one, then you may wish to define `Gray :: Colours; Gray = Grey` just in case another developer thinks the other spelling is better.

Comment: @Ramon Snir: Yes, that would sound sensible, to define a synonym. However, your code does not compile: functions/variables are not allowed to be uppercase in Haskell. and `gray :: Colours; gray = Grey` would break the naming convention for the user. -- the reason I am trying to have these synonyms is that I'm trying to model/embed a domain specific language.

Comment: @Ramon Snir: True, an answer could be to use only "smart constructors", not to export the data constructors at all, but rather functions with `white = White; gray = Gray; grey = Gray; -- ...` but that defies somewhat the purpose of my question not to have to type several hundred lines more.

Comment: So you have a choice between supporting alternate spellings of `Grey` and hundreds of lines of boilerplate. I know which one I'd choose...

Comment: +1 because the example might be contrieved and you are probably looking for trouble, but the question 'is there a way to call *super* or default implementation of a class' is a good question.

Comment: If you want to write code that is aware of the structure of the data types you should have a look into *generics*. The low level interface is via the Data.Typeable interface and there are many generic programming libs built on top of that. I am not convinced that this is good for your example (I would much rather just use a single constructor) but its very useful specially when you have nested data structures (for example, "return a list of all Expressions in this complex AST")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the derived `Enum` instance :

```
data ColourName = Gray | Grey | ...
  deriving (Read, Show, Enum)

instance Eq ColourName where
  Gray == Grey = True
  Grey == Gray = True
  a == b = fromEnum a == fromEnum b
```

Edit: You can also use `PatternSynonyms` with GHC 7.8+. It works like a smart constructor, but can also be used in pattern matches.

```
pattern Gray = Grey
```

Comment: This clearly solves my problem, but semantically seems to be a hack. I mean, there is no natural to the colours ("Class `Enum` defines operations on sequentially ordered types."), and `succ` and `pred` do not make naturally sense for colour data. (It's an entirely different question, that all computer implementations provide a colourmap, but colours themselves are not sequentially orderable).

Comment: Yes I concede that they are not semantically equivalent, as cdk pointed out. But it should not break code, and allows you to enumerate values, even if there is no semantics in the order. This is the same issue with `Ord` : it doesn't always make sense to derive, but it allows efficient maps. Pattern synonyms are the closest to what you want, but require recent compiler support.

Comment: My understanding of `enum`s ids not one that requires an ordering to exist. And yes, I'm aware of the `succ` and `pred` methods.

Answer (score 9):

Do not do this. It won't work well with pattern matching. It will break something like

```
f Gray = g
f x    = h
```

because pattern matching does not care about your `Eq` instance.

By break, I mean it won't have the behavior you want, since `f Grey` would end up calling `h` rather than `g`, even though you would expect for `f x == f y` for all `x == y`. This means the programmer has to explicitly remember to make cases for both `f Gray` and `f Grey` which is just dumb.

If you are determined to have an ugly hack to allow for alternate spellings, I suppose you can do

```
#define Gray Grey
```

with CPP enabled.

Comment: Or use PatternSynonyms.

Comment: I think this is the best answer for most purposes. In general, programmers using your code should read your documentation and use whichever spelling you've chosen. However, this solution moves the problem elsewhere: to your `Read` and `Show` instances.

Comment: @dfeuer: "let the user read your docs" is not an option, if there is an external specification for the DSL syntax...

Answer (score 7):

By definition the values `Grey` and `Gray` are not equal. There is nothing that suggests that they should be equal, except the extra semantics you've attached to them. I'd say this is an abuse of the `Eq` typeclass.

Define a function to handle these additional semantics:

```
sameColour :: Color -> Color -> Bool
sameColour Grey Gray = True
sameColour Gray Grey = True
sameColor  a    b    = a == b
```

this can easily be extended to handle multiple colour "synonyms"

Comment: This is what I would suggest as the most correct answer, since you could pretty easily run into issues with certain data structures that depend on the `Eq` instance being well behaved.  Having a different function for "human" comparison avoids this issue

Comment: @bheklir define well-behaved. This definition is transitive, reflexive and symmetric. There is no reason to assume different constructors yield unequal elements. Ex.: `Data.Ratio.%`

Answer (score 6):

Similarly to Piezoid's answer, you could make it a bit less efficient by using the `Show` instance to compare them:

```
data ColourName = Gray | Grey | ...
    deriving (Show, Read)

instance Eq ColourName where
    Gray == Grey = True
    Grey == Gray = True
    a == b = show a == show b
```

Then you don't have to rely on using `Enum`, but you will have a bit of a performance hit from having to compare strings.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `newtype` here:

```
newtype ColourNameEquatingGrayAndGrey = CNEGAG ColourName
instance Eq ColourNameEquatingGrayAndGrey where
    CNEGAG Gray == CNEGAG Grey = True
    CNEGAG Grey == CNEGAG Gray = True
    CNEGAG a    == CNEGAG b    = a == b
```

(Sorry about the silly type and constructor names...)

This allows you to keep `deriving Eq`, it makes you be very explicit about where in your code you are lumping the different spellings together, and you can still use library functions such as `nub` (as compared to having to switch over to `nubBy sameColour` (as in @cdk's answer) or something like that). You can also make your own `Show` instance, should you need one, and the runtime cost should be minimal.

The only downside I can think of right now is that pattern matching becomes more cumbersome, but I'm guessing that with 100s of alternatives that's not something you do at the drop of a hat!